# Coherent risk measure

Tags: expected-shortfall

One of the characteristics of a Coherent risk measure is `Positive homogeneity` (ref, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure).

`Expected Shortfall` is considered to be a conhorent risk measure. Does it mean that it satisfy `Positive homogeneity` for all kinds of distribution of underlying risk factor?

I understand that if the statistical distribution is Location and scale invariant (e.g. `Normal distribution`), then `Expected shortfall` can be assumed to follow `Positive homogeneity`, but how can it be generalised for all kind of statistical distributions with support as Real line?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/QRM/RiskMeasures_MasterSlides.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be. Consider a random variable $X$ with support $\mathbb{R}$ that we'll think of as returns in a portfolio, with cdf $F$ with inverse $F^{-1}$. (Let's assume also that it has a pdf $p$.)

Then, for a confidence level $\alpha$, for example $95\%$, the expected shortfall is

$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{-\infty}^{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}xp(x)dx$$

Let $c>0$ be a positive scalar, and consider the distribution of $Y=cX$. This random variable has cdf $F_c$ and pdf $p_c$. Similarly, it has expected shortfall given by

$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{-\infty}^{F_c^{-1}(1-\alpha)}yp_c(y)dy$$

Considering the properties of $F_c$, we see that
$F_c(x) = P( Y< x) = P(cX < x) = P(X < \frac{x}{c}) = F(\frac{x}{c})$, and similarly $F_c^{-1}(x) = cF^{-1}(x)$. and so $p_c(x) = \frac{p(\frac{x}{c})}{c}$.

This gives us:

$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{-\infty}^{cF^{-1}(1-\alpha)}y\frac{p(\frac{y}{c})}{c}dy$$

A change of variables $y=cx, dy=cdx$ gives us

$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{-\infty}^{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}cxp(x)dx = \frac{c}{1-\alpha} \int_{-\infty}^{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}xp(x)dx$$

which is exactly $c$ times our initial definition.

Comment: Very nice mathematical proof.

Comment: Thank you. I think there are ways of showing it somewhat more "cleanly" (e.g., if you show using the same definitions that $\mathbb{1}_{Y<F_c(1-\alpha)} = \mathbb{1}_{X<F(1-\alpha)} $ then you can show that $\mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{1}_{Y<F_c(1-\alpha)} ) = c\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{X<F(1-\alpha)}) $
but they work out to the same idea

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're happy that PnL distribution is a **positive $\Sigma$-measurable function** (can it not be?) then, yes, ES measure is always positively homogeneous.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_of_Positive_Measurable_Function_is_Positive_Homogeneous